# How to access JSON object using PHP

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

I have REST API and looks like below :

```
{
"rajaongkir": {
    "query": {
        "key": "b5231ee43b8ee75764bd6a289c4c5745"
    },
    "status": {
        "code": 200,
        "description": "OK"
    },
    "results": [
        {
            "city_id": "1",
            "province_id": "21",
            "province": "Nanggroe Aceh Darussalam (NAD)",
            "type": "Kabupaten",
            "city_name": "Aceh Barat",
            "postal_code": "23681"
        },
        {
            "city_id": "2",
            "province_id": "21",
            "province": "Nanggroe Aceh Darussalam (NAD)",
            "type": "Kabupaten",
            "city_name": "Aceh Barat Daya",
            "postal_code": "23764"
        }
     ]
  }
}
```

I want to consume this API. I call the object like code below :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<title>Raja Ongkir</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Raja Ongkir</h1>
  <?php 
    echo var_dump($data->rajaongkir->results[0]); 
  ?>
</body>
</html>
```

If I call first element of JSON using this line

> echo var_dump($data->rajaongkir->results[0]);

OR

> echo var_dump($data->rajaongkir->results[0]->city_name);

I got the output that I want. But If I try to get all **city_id** or **city_name** in **results** object, using this code

> echo var_dump($data->rajaongkir->results->city_name);

I got this error

> Message: Trying to get property 'city_name' of non-object

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use loop for all city name.
For example :

```
foreach ($data->rajaongkir->results as $v) {
   echo $v->city_name."\n";
}
```

Comment: How can I get just first element of JSON? I try **$v->city_name[0]** I got error.

Comment: if you use loop it run for each element in results. if you only want to reach city_name in first object u can try this. `echo $data->rajaongkir->results[0]->city_name;`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following instead:

```
$all_city_names = array_column(json_decode($data->rajaongkir->results, true), 
                               'city_name');

// Display all the city name(s)
var_dump($all_city_names);
```

**Details**:

- [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), with second parameter set to `true`, will convert the JSON to array [of arrays].
- [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) function can be used to extract a one-dimensional array of a particular key values, out of a two-dimensional array.